# WS: what to return when saving?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am creating a simple WS CRUD using Apache CXF. This is what I have so far:

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    private IUserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public User getUser(Long id) {
        return userDAO.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String saveUser(User u) {
        userDAO.persist(u);
        return "ok";
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String updateUser(User u) {
        userDAO.merge(u);
        return "ok";
    }

    @Override
    public String deleteUser(Long id) {
        userDAO.remove(id);
        return "ok";
    }


}
```

I based this example on a tutorial I found over the net, but I was wondering whether it's good practice to return simple "ok" strings after modification methods. What would be the best solution here?

Answer (score 2):

I'd return void.  The absence of an exception implies it worked fine.

Comment: How would you manage exceptions? For instance I got a "Duplicate key exception" and my service returns `<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>ORA-00001: unique constraint (CNTXES.PK_USER) violated
; SQL [n/a]; constraint [CNTXES.PK_USER]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CNTXES.PK_USER) violated</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>` , is this good practice?

Comment: Add an @ExceptionHandler to controller to handle exceptions.  Depends on what you want to do when that happens.  Or you could wrap the caller with a try/catch, if you expect that to happen sometimes.   If you expect that to happen a lot, you could do a query first to check for uniqueness

Comment: Thing is -- I am not using spring mvc, and I don't have controllers.: just a service layer with bean injection of the DAOs, and the core spring libraries.